Missing types not shown as errors in VAL
Consider the following set of types for a PDDL domain:
(:types aType1 aType2 aType3 - object)

where predicates and actions have parameters of all 3 types above. I have removed one of the types (say aType1) from above. When running VAL, I do not seem to get any errors displayed. Are there other tools that may discover this error?

I don't know why people downvoted this question. It might be off-topic, but it's related to AI, and the action that you should take, voter, is to Close, then choose the closing reason, not downvote. Downvoting doesn't help the OP to understand that the question is off-topic. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Downvote is indeed weird...question is on-topic. Trying something out to see if there's a decent answer.

@haz Asking for tools is generally off-topic here, as we focus on the theory, but this question is still related to AI. I was just pointing out that, if a question is off-topic, people should vote to close it, not downvote it, unless there's also a reason to downvote it, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Yes, the pddl Python library can help you out here! It's pip installable (pip install pddl), and trying to parse the domain file will fail:
from pddl import parse_domain
domain = parse_domain('domain.pddl')

